Haunted House / Delusion Film mid 2000s?
I downloaded the film and watched it, 10(+) years ago. A decent budget, but nothing with any notable actors at the time.
There is a couple who buys a home. During their time in the house, ghosts are seen, specifically a small girl disciplined by her father at the dinner table.
There is a portion where someone is visiting the wife of the home and a giant crack appears through the fireplace wall. She is trying to have a psychic or someone diagnose the house.
I do remember that in the end, she didn't have a husband. She imagined him, and the paramedics name who rescues her in the end (I wanna say his name was 'Robert') ends up being the explanation of how she imagined everything. 
Searching for Haunted House Movies, Delusions, not having a name is a giant wormhole. I am hoping some of these details might hit someone's memory who saw the same movie. 

This is The Occupants (2014).

Lucy has a new husband, a new home and a new baby, but old ghosts won't let her be. She tries to help the tortured souls break free of their torment and move on, but soon finds these ghosts don't want her help.

The dinner scene is here;




The twist is as you've described it. It turns out that the husband isn't real.


This was correct!
Had a terrible time finding a torrent, but FilmRise has the entire movie for free on YouTube. Thank you!

@823FM - No problem, and thanks for the acceptance!
